# @CachePut handle error

Tags: java, spring, caching, memcached

I'm working with Spring, in particular with Spring Cache Abstraction, and I will like to know what happens when I have a method with the annotation **@CachePut** and the cache is down, how can I realize about that situation? The code inside saveSession method will executes after putting the value in the cache, but it will executed in case of success or failure, and I want to be aware of what is happening.

```
@CachePut(value = value , key = key)
public SessionCache saveSession(String value, SessionCache sessionCache) {
   ...
}
```